# How to open a dialog style list when using spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-spinner

This is the UI i am getting when using spinner.

[image]

But i want following pop up style layout when user taps on dropdown.

[image]

This is my code.

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);

        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

Comment: You need to design custom dialog and for `Spinner` you need to create design like `spinner` and  `on click` it show this custom `dialog`.

Comment: You need to use the custom dialog with a spinner but you have to maintain the style as well. The second design is the old version of android like KitKat so it is showing like this.